# Convert a TIO answer to a CMC answer

Tags: code-golf, string, parsing

Let's for once do something useful.

Given the text from a Try It Online codegolf submission, produce the equivalent Chat Mini Challenge submission, which is of the form

```
Language, N bytes: [`code`](URL)
```

or (if submission is a single byte – TIO will add a trailing s on the first line only if needed)

```
Language, 1 byte: [`code`](URL)
```

You may assume that the submission

- has only one line
- does not contain backticks (`` ` ``)
- has no leading whitespace
- has a regular format like in the examples below; the code line is indented with four spaces (    ), not with HTML tags (`<pre><code>`…`</code></pre>`), i.e. no trailing whitespace.

**Note that the submission may have a syntax highlighting tag. See last example.**

You may optionally include the title text, i.e. `…url "Language - Try It Online"`.

#### Examples

Given

```
# [05AB1E], 1 byte

    Ô

[Try it online!][TIO-j3v72bss]

[05AB1E]: https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E
[TIO-j3v72bss]: https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8JT//zNSgSAnJycfDAA "05AB1E – Try It Online"
```

return

```
05AB1E, 1 byte: [`Ô`](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8JT//zNSgSAnJycfDAA)
```

or

```
05AB1E, 1 byte: [`Ô`](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8JT//zNSgSAnJycfDAA "05AB1E – Try It Online")
```

Given

```
# [Brachylog], 4 bytes

    ḅhᵐc

[Try it online!][TIO-j3v75978]

[Brachylog]: https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog
[TIO-j3v75978]: https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//@GO1oyHWyck//@vlJGampOTDwZK/6MA "Brachylog – Try It Online"
```

return

```
Brachylog, 4 bytes: [`ḅhᵐc`](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//@GO1oyHWyck//@vlJGampOTDwZK/6MA)
```

Given

```
# [APL (Dyalog Unicode)], 15 bytes

<!-- language-all: lang-apl -->

    ⍴⍨¨⍳

[Try it online!][TIO-j44jgrps]

[APL (Dyalog Unicode)]: https://www.dyalog.com/
[TIO-j44jgrps]: https://tio.run/##AScA2P9hcGwtZHlhbG9n//9m4oaQ4o204o2owqjijbP//zcxNjDijLZmIDQ "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online"
```

return

```
APL (Dyalog Unicode), 15 bytes: [`⍴⍨¨⍳`](https://tio.run/##AScA2P9hcGwtZHlhbG9n//9m4oaQ4o204o2owqjijbP//zcxNjDijLZmIDQ)
```

Comment: Can we assume the language name does not contain a `]`?

Comment: No language name on TIO has `]` though.

Comment: True, I guess. May we assume the answer does not have any *leading* whitespace?

Comment: @ETHproductions Yes, because otherwise the backticks won't work. I'll edit.

Comment: @ais523 I think the 4th assumption already listed covers the secondary output format.

Comment: @ais523 the first issues is dealt with as ETHproductions notes. The syntax highlighting, hm, I guess it should.

Comment: Code golf is useful ಠ_ಠ

Comment: @Adám I somehow missed that

Answer (score 6):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <s>37</s>, 35 bytes

```
ç^</dj
H3xf]x3Ji[`A`]Jd2/: 
xr(A)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY9BTsJAFIb3cwU2D7qBxOko1AUNMWlCAiVESsQNTQ1DW9uZDB0sgy2uvAArDyF7PYHepBeptRtjwp@8xZ//vbz/ey7L7/eHAQk4GvfyRy/vTZi7algrrzEJusQElKdtq1OWGriWM4X28ECFjOA@Yb4Mwo53AVfXsD6ocIfQoIkxCJpEexqFmAph1g7TrQCMbxCCSsXxszievk7F8QMhd5EegCmQiWBJ2PTchT3D3DB4lG53XpWf/WlCrNR2ZxKSZZke1Knuyw1B/@//9hSTerpPiKZZd77VdfqxP8rUcizi9aifENLfGJLODdm9rEZmT5zxtUPIi5/f8iHj0@XGHs6hda4NFK9v8IthK5jVGK0f)

Comment: I tried using the surround plugin that's sort of bundled with V, but it kept trimming whitespace off the end, which I think disqualifies it.

Comment: Can I bother you to add support for the syntax highlighting tag?

Comment: @nmjcman101 Umm, I think you can assume trailing whitespace doesn't exist.

Comment: @Adám Well, that kinda seems like pointlessly changing the spec in the middle, but I guess I can support it.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Well, it was in sandbox for a while. And no-one thought of that. I wouldn't have made the change if it wasn't for the actual use value of these submissions. Sorry about that. Have some ice cream: 

Comment: @DJMcMayhem I just did `ds[` for the language brackets and then tried `ys$[` for the actual code oneliner.  I think that `ys$]` will skip adding extra whitespace, and you should be able to do `ys$\`` to surround with backticks also

Comment: @nmjcman101 Yeah, I did know about the difference between `ys$[` and `ys$]`, but since we're surrounding it with backticks *and* brackets, it's actually shorter to just put them in manually.

Comment: Could you use `d/   ` instead of `ç^</dj` for both 2 bytes and back to Vim compatibility? [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU/NToNAGLzvK/TytVzaxGUV8QAxJkSSCmlsG@ulhKRboPxkYRG2Ap58gZ58id71CXwUXgSxF2PSwxwmM5OZee2663rn1rZPAADZ1NkMjI07sH2F6IDqYryD@0nXSeAYixmMzYYyHsJzFnvcDybuBVzdwLYRQYnQ7RBjYDQL9zQMMGVMPzFMcwYY3yHUN0B7@GoPx@9je/hEyFkVDcQCeMbiLBi6zsqa40RVk7DIS7fXz3bqEAmRlzohVVXJ/kmVPZ4S9D//5xMxl4t9RiTJePIMZaFF3rQS6wcWbadaRoiWqpwuVa5c9uDVSxIn2wUhb179mJhxMlunlrmE0bk10L5/wO8NS8D8dGP0Aw "V – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>113</s> <s>103</s> <s>98</s> 91 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to Value Ink.*

If you can, I could totally use some help with the regex. ><

```python
lambda s:re.sub('(?s)# .(.*)](.*?)\n.* {4}(.*?)\n.+: (.*)',r'\1\2: [`\3`](\4)',s)
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY/BToNAEIbv@xQjHFhq3ZVSoyExDU09tEnbQ7mxJIUCZU1ZyO5iQo2J76Bv5Jv4IkitxjiHSWb@@f78U7e6qITb5fesO8RlksagPJkR1STYwhNlm0AwGdhR3yY2E2QAz@OX3@HSg5NoDaXFHDbyINwydxthNu53yka8rCupQWZdLbnQOMeGYZgQXt/4U@chGoIDSaszhKCvj3eEwkC2wDVU4sBFdhGFwXx99eg@3Y4SpaJe/yE9KLSulUfpnuuiSciuKqmfSh6LtMwEPZ@h//gfpHlFZCOoaS6P01UwWyxpTundIqD0uNrsN75YtLt85vtgnJ3g8/UNTtnmGtbf2Vj/iWHb3Rc)

Comment: Can I bother you to add support for the syntax highlighting tag?

Comment: Great, thanks. Sorry about that.

Comment: No need to use `\s` to match the code block part; replace it with a literal space character. Also the expected output doesn't have the `"Language - Try It Online"` segment, so you need to change your last group to `(\S*)` to match correctly, so the byte count comes out around the same.

Comment: Actually, it turns out you can keep that Try It Online part. In that case, changing `\s` to a space will save 1 byte.

Comment: Yup, I was the one who asked that question. ;)

Comment: This is late, but you can do `<sp><sp>+` in place of `<sp>{4}` (-1 byte). Also, with Python 3.6, you can use `(?s:...)` to apply dot-all to only part of the regex (-2 bytes). [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY/BaoNAEIbvPsVUD65JutvElpaFEgzpIUKSQ7y5QjRq3BJX2V0L5tR3SN@ob9IXsdoUSucwMP/M9/NP3eqiEm6XP7PuFJdJGoOiMsOqSZBtAUZ45ERDQ3NF8Qhg3A9zhwk8pjDojj2RNpuyGYVwz9x9hNh9rynH4GVdSQ0y62rJhUY5Mk3TgvDuwVtMX6IJTCFpdWYY0Nfnh2GEgWyBa6jEiYvsJgqD1fb21X17nCVKRf3@l6RQaF0rSsiR66JJ8KEqiZdKHou0zAS5nhn/8T9I8wrLRhDLWp8Xm2Dpr0lOyJMfEHLe7I47T/jtIV96HphXJ/h6v8CQbaVh@5ON9Z@YjtN9Aw)

Comment: Actually, even better: ditch the flag entirely and use `[^\t]` (with `\t` representing a literal tab character) when you need to match all characters including newlines: [86 bytes](https://tio.run/##VY/BToNAEIbP7lOMcADaypai0ZB4oKmHkrQ9lBu7plCgrCkL2V1M6Ml30DfyTfoiCFZjnMPkz8x8f/6pW1VU3O3yR9Id4zJJY5CeyGzZJKahg23aI4sOLXq@oiOA8a8eezBIYyIM4pCZB9GOuDtqktt@Ji3EyroSCkTW1YJxZeampmk6RNM7f@480Qk4kLQqQwj6@vxAKApFC0xBxY@MZ9c0Cpebmxf39X6WSEn7/Q/pQaFULT2MD0wVTWLvqxL7qWAxT8uM48sZ@o//QYpVtmg41vXVab4OF8EK5xg/BCHGp/X2sPV50O7zhe@DdnGC89s7DNmWCjbf2Uj/iWZZ3Rc)

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>54</s> <s>48</s> <s>52</s> <s>57</s> 48 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @MartinEnder, 1 byte thanks to @Riley*

```
...(.+)[^@]+    (.+)[^@]+: 
$1: [`$2`](
1`]

$
)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7LSsNAGIX38xR/myxa6swQL60GkXqB3ogRDAiGSKYhJKOTTEgnlXHlxr3gswi@Tn2RmHYR9azOgf//ziljxXNW14SQHhn0/YdxMIBGbbABmZYNfmjuh0EPWWGAkIn6dW2Af1GyKNVCJsEeHMJSq3iF0GkHYxAsTyqWxPbOYSYEYHyG0Ba9@XpLN5/vEUK@V2rgCmQueB53At@bufjxYD06OhkdNz1/CmxIlSpWNqUJV2m1JJHM6PyyynhO2yv0H/D7o7gkZZVTw7jVxcJzhvLFETfXtKR0PHEtqad3OnpqwlrMJywrXO/q@X5Bh845dFs6fL9@wHbxTIG7W9z9AQ) This assumes there won't be an `@` in the language name, which should be fine...

Comment: you could just replace `^# \[` with `^...` I think

Comment: @MartinEnder Thanks, I think that works...

Comment: Can you skip the `^` and `$`? It should always match the whole string anyway.

Comment: @Riley That would fail if... oh shoot, mine does too...

Comment: This doesn't work if the code contains `<space>"`, but I don't know if you need to handle that. I'm guessing you just noticed that to.

Comment: @Riley Yeah, fixed now. The `^` can be removed though AFAICT.

Comment: Can I bother you to add support for the syntax highlighting tag?

Comment: @Adám Ah sorry, fixed.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 50 bytes

```
']¡J¦¦¦|J|`‚ʒнðQ}`ðÛ|D`θ'"Êi\|ë\}θ#1èr"ÿ: [`ÿ`](ÿ)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU@xasJQFN3zFddkUKHxqcTBUApCwCpSldrFGMhLDPGFmGdjJLVEcBZc2q2dupRAoQjtLuRt/Yz8SKoupeC93OFwzuHcU65ho2JlWV5L3trJ@3GjdqSn65efpzKL2a6/0tmOvUaKnnyyOM@zDRlF7GO0OkKhwmKfZ3sZVJ3tda3A9sUsE0Bt9DpQUJbYpTbcecSkY6uoXUClBsYysOYcd5kTRXCxZy@wbYnYdeUTEvHMBVG84jg4TLr9TrdxEqfbL45TB/4SSADUc4ln5TR10OqKjiQ5tj@bawf@bKYMkyCYzWWEwjAsjU9syaRTxP33/@kCQkv@wkOC0Lg1G9VefWI2w2B47U6MZt1DqD6VKO5LtFo@HA3vHeIYPYQezYcbRyFOZzhtKX3gz30D6foZjjVaAXRPNfhf)

*Now supports syntax highlighting too!*

`н` is replaced by `0è` and `θ` is replaced by `®è` since those aren't pulled to TIO yet.

I just wonder how to shorten `¦¦¦`...

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), 73 bytes

```js
f=
s=>s.replace(/...(.*)](.*)[^]+    (.*)[^]+: (.*) ".*/,"$1$2: [`$3`]($4)")
```

```html
<textarea rows=8 cols=75 oninput=o.textContent=this.value==f(this.value)?``:f(this.value)></textarea><pre id=o>
```

Comment: The answer I was waiting for. Can this be made into a bookmarklet? Otherwise I'll just bookmark it.

Comment: @Adám `alert(prompt().replace(...))` might work, if the prompt will let you paste multiple lines in some way (the regexp doesn't actually need the newlines to be present).

Comment: Hm, I get the unmodified post as result. Maybe we can inject your code into TIO…

Comment: I was also working on a similar solution, but I didn't know about `[^]` to match _anything_. I have learnt something new from your solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## MATLAB/[Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>120</s> 126 bytes

```matlab
@(a)strjoin(regexprep(strsplit(a,'\n'),{'\[.+\]: (.+) ".+','^[\[<].+','# \[(.+)\](.+)','^ +'},{'`]($1)','','$1$2: [`',''}),'')
```

This should work. For MATLAB it won't work with Unicode characters though I don't think, mostly because MATLAB sucks when it comes to odd characters. However it will work with Unicode for Octave, or at least TIO seems to be able to cope.

It should also handle submissions both with and without the `<-- -->` syntax highlighting.

*Updates*:

1. Added 4 bytes as I missed the `@(a)` when copying over
2. Added 2 bytes to add back ticks around the code in the output

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU7bSsNAEP2VsS1sQmLWeGk1@FAvUNtSIxgQ3Kw0DaHZmmbDZhuNUvDFd8FvEfyd@iNxU6R1GIaZM@ecGR7KoIiqqqsFei7FjLNUE9E0es5ElGkKybOESS0wkZ8i3XxFPrEMnzqgWYYODctAJnogPjml67YJPqk3Pq1rvQMDLZVsTLWWXQMqW3Zr3wEyrqelropeBWmuEaUm5yII4zLhU2rCIUxKGeUI7L06EahYfb/Hq6@PcAMST5TAJPA0YWm0Q4nXd3dnB0Xn6KRzTLe0rbEDsZRZ7mA8ZTJeTKyQz/HgYjFnKd6w0J/5f7OtUDJuiUWKm83bMht6ozZ/GSU311hg3O25Ni@v7srwUQ1FMugF88z1Lp/uh7g9OoPG5gT8vH1C/X1fgrv@voGoXv0C)

Comment: Can this be run on [TIO Octave](https://tio.run/#octave)?

Comment: @Adám it does indeed. I've updated the answer with TIO link.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 85 bytes

```ruby
->s{s[/.*/].gsub(/# .|\]/){}+": [`#{s[/(?<=  )\S.*/]}`](#{s=~/TIO-\w+.: (\S+)/;$1})"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZLZkppQEIbvfYozmgvNBJFhUczMhEVAEXFhUUetGkVkCYsIiDIxlXfIG@ZFDM5NKndJ353@v67@qk4f0s35untaXqHn@C1ewPWP8KpuxemmCldA/dtyBdfeLvflNli8Vm559cvjEwC1pXIDL6@ratF9@g6rvSG0zO7rbVBdKvc1@PMH5FIrX677NInBrm6sPQ8oaqcn1w/menutgMWkWLz6BFoY2JwTMy6VHu8gCHjrwErXlgkVA@33F3QoQABBz6USKOp/NP/VslRaqIczcBIQBp4TmHerxY10MSzw8CO6KvJ32zawk2Qft2E4y7L6zQu6GdbDgwWX/h75gyZOWKABXKlsNFLehKLFyUju2AJhyYcjRUQ2SwRrX2TmXCqPYiZlJhzDsbTkifhk7XtNWldg@@gijNsS@b5k733XFSVhY/r57lgQE51MmWnE27uepVsRJdppA5N1l6W7uCobva3jzhNLEn1hfyIJmqI1airoRIYkHjZEY0/xHQ5ZPwyYKa@nBqVSkSdnW17g1xOpw@9TAseEFt/X9q5zIrVcsNzhXJ0PdIPMepsgyLudzny6JxEaz4jBSOIdJ41QjhZHJIVoyRnR2MwNWNO3mcyS@@ND1A/hHb7rNoxzNJqdFE/qD4yAHrMoKrciotijpDMcaTRZf5icHJjiBXYmClzMiaInbAlDm2aC2ZDIIwy7okbQITkOOp2hkus8iibpC3Y@vYxmYXNO5jlrBgmlMbsW1y0izDLR@RbBLbXlR5TKoxNDMQ9HZZxaUvMrE0cj9cF2FDoY5G43nGWgfPt38OvHT3A7kF4Chu8HUv4N)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 101 bytes

```python
a=input().split('\n')
print'%s%s: [`%s`](%s)'%tuple(a[0][3:].split(']')+[a[-6][4:],a[-1].split()[1]])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5db4IwFIbv9ys6CSnNlPLhNkeyC4y7kES9kLu2iYAoXbA0tCzin0fQme1cnZPzvk8e2eqiEl7XJZ9cyEZbyFay5NqCVED0JGsuNDSVqQJAdqbaMctUCJq6kWVuJcRhxA/Yo8IgeiEJmbwxMg3YuN/cxw8RlzHUddAAxHkN5@4XGwMXpK3OqaAC9EPPmU/PH9PhJnHdAq5BJUou8mdG4uVm8u3/vHupUuyW@KUEoNBaqgDjI9dFk9pZdcLhvuaJ2J9yge@xgfif8NfSvLLrRmDDWF3m63gRrfAB41kUY3xZb4/bUERtdliEIRjdUb1n7tHzzOldfTB4LjXY3DxH8Ao) or [Try all test cases](https://tio.run/##hZJrj5pAFIa/@ytmNQZJF0cUXSVtU7Y2ru562WjTRCDZ4SKMhYHCsIh/3g54wQ92S0KYk3POe877MGFG3YC0DwfL3oBNw@DlCkBfjGYcepg2OI1wfAVENk0iwtXjeiwD9a0ev@mNesxzdZqEnt1AaktXO7J@btI5/pOKVKGnq5Ks37OTeM7xqqjr/CF1sWcDkc0KI0woG4xJmLA0f@BqQG11lUfxh34PRGBk1NaIRgB7tJ3Z0XYDKY/VVZQBTEFAPEzsO11djefCtvP@0DbiWC8qTioycCkNYxlCB1M3MZpm4EPFijAilm8TeCzLFa8Vyi6Kg2aUEFirTfePs9VwMoUbCPuTFYT72dJZKmSSmZuhooDqUYrtabe1Xb/Fdu2AfM8xBfNizypXyf09Rsh0My9wmEWpsBiXHm1R2xl91t91T0GXCbXMD113Bw/9o@tS@6bxyffExwReqq58Fxq3fC@z8Hk17QX7qbeYwQjCb6O5GGRPvzLzNwvevckI@eF8NUzXz7A3ZSAu8v9noSxeQGOYobz4J8FmYNl8/ue7JZfPd4IAPEScBDm2gDxPLiIBhR4QhK9X6PJRFiMmlWfEUJrt4/eS7/wbpiRtnSg8XaGby5WI0jRtWkW2YHtmeZa4xVJZmkp7MXDNUUrXT55rjAYEwoEvBehVCtot9gbpny3eGgt2v8zdbDvE25e1Px6@guqtdT4m/Bc)

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 92 bytes

```php
<?=preg_filter("<...(.+)\](, \d+ \w+).* {4}(\S+).*: (\S+).*>s","$1$2: [`$3`]($4)",$_GET[0]);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVFbasJQEP2/q5jGgElN7lWbfhhfCBYrSFW0PyZBY0zzIOamyZXUlkI34Fc34X@7gi4lG7FRWkrBgYEznBnOnJnIjQ6NduRGCPHz3s1UKxvNYgG0zmgAQndrBtSB@9Cz6MoWDQkq17DcMjtBqHEhyxCYobMxHVs2g0A9VbIZBSDLLYQgj2z3me32X/ts94GQNo234DGgYeCF9oWhTftD2VcU34mjxMj5s5oquIxFiUpImqZ4dWKxRdcE/Z//62MexfEmJIVCZ2J1qqOaa/VSNrsN3GWvFhJSWyvUHCu0Ws6Tpo@@5y9HhDxbT3d@1/MHs3W/Owbu3DaQvb3D0UafwfBkgyvWUbuVn7AZxbYzf/ACZscC18AYC7gk6oYggb4qgZ6WRHwJL8qroE@OUIUf0Eo4ieMrfFUFbcFfLQyBV0RO@v2GWD8cvgE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>43</s> <s>39</s> 38 bytes

```
[a@>3DC']": [`"g@-6|>s"`]("(g@v^s1)')]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7NrsFAGIZv5TNdIMF3SvykC@k4tdCELnTXjFCqRpg2nSGpnIV74I7ciRsZReTEu36fJ0/KU62Dhd1vOb9lRiwI5iS2652/viRzViGV2D7OpFktV5nW2oDgp00H5pDVwIQwV5HWUOx2LSR@lgNXkIgdF1GJBf7Iq29bx24zlLKAP6QFG6VSaSHGXG0OYWOZ7JGuMr4Qq30k8H3T3/g/pHjSyA4CDWN8Gkx8xx3jGrHn@oinyTSeUuHmy7VDKZC3Ce7nCzzbRgq8Vxt5AA)

Takes the lines as separate command-line arguments. An example invocation could look like:

```
> pip.py -f convert.pip "# [05AB1E], 1 byte" "" "    Ô" "" "[Try it online!][TIO-j3v72bss]" "" "[05AB1E]: https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E" "[TIO-j3v72bss]: https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8JT//zNSgSAnJycfDAA \"05AB1E – Try It Online\""
```

<sup>though actually this doesn't work for me because Windows `cmd` complains about the `Ô`... [inarticulate muttering]</sup>

--At any rate, it works on TIO. Or, use the `-r` flag and take input from lines of stdin instead.

Assumes that the language name will not contain `]` (which would break the markdown anyway).

#### Explanation

```
                                        g is list of cmdline args; a is 1st arg;
                                        s is space; v is -1 (implicit)
[                                    ]  Build a list with these elements:
 a@>3                                    1st line, sans first three characters,
     DC']                                 with the ] character deleted
         ": [`"                          This string
               g@-6                      6th line from the end (the code)
                   |>s                    with leading spaces stripped
                      "`]("              This string
                            g@v          Last line (containing the URL)
                               ^s         split on spaces
                           (     1)       get element at index 1
                                   ')    This character
                                        By default, the list is concatenated and printed
```