# Answer templating

Tags: code-golf, string

## Context

Just look around! Whenever someone posts an answer, the same template is followed over and over again! A first line with the byte count and language name. Then the code. Then the TIO link. This is the basic skeleton almost everyone follows.

## Task

Your task, should you choose to accept it, is to write a program/function/procedure/etc that takes as input the variable bits and produces the basic CGCC answer.

## Input

The language name, some code and a TIO link, in any sensible formats. For the language name and the TIO link, a string is suggested. For the code, sensible formats include a string with possibly some newlines, or a list of strings, one string per line.

Additionally, you may also take the byte count as input. If you don't, you have to compute it yourself (if you compute it yourself, you can assume the byte count equals the length of the code string).

You have to support that the input strings may contain any printable, non-whitespace ASCII characters plus the space. The only exclusion being the newlines in the source code. You don't have to worry about the weird characters used by golfing languages in their code pages.

The inputs may be ordered in any way you like.

## Output

You should output this raw content:

```
# {name}, {byte count} bytes

    {code}

You can [try it online][tio]!

[tio]: {link}
```

Where `{name}`, `{byte count}`, `{code}` and `{link}` should be filled in by your code. Three of those are inputs, the byte count should be computed within your code if you chose not to receive it as input (you can assume the byte count is equal to the number of characters in the `code` argument). Beware that the code given may be multiline, in which case the `{code}` section must be indented by 4 spaces for each line of code.

## Test cases

You can [check some test cases](https://tio.run/##lVJNb9swDL3rV9AKsNmr49TtTsEMBAiwj8OAHXYpXKNVHDkWKsuGRHcNgvz2jLKWDDusQH0waZl8fO@Jwx7b3tyeTii7QQuUUADnfAYHLczumFKUZoftETZ7lI4xoOdQ91t5ZOyuH6EWBkq0e1AIvdHKyKpE1VcRY1NcwmG0@kiYjG1lA03sgVPwEClQ/VOynECp4rPS2oEygK0EYdwvaeHCq@ktrL@s11C3QntS0mWBzqPHeoRO7GFDfdCNGpVnAg6tMrvsjB/KgyDSSUnsW5Pp2Gd06ENmJc2sZczvDU@B3hNAEvqtxNGaC7GMiHUCJ1lF0BYmFCEEqUXQS1YUk@aTr/Re/5guAG45@0OAa9FttgJelvBylXNGLf60RRzccrEgTzM7msVsCDfH2UAaMf7XV2pKiG74xef8w8dr@jzP/Crck9T6MvKekTlxlCeU5yw2kfKZgSuIzTyP1DxPvHv/Y9Ke4d7O5Lugqyb3VC3@GtCU@qGi5KfqpFut4m9Nue5Hg6VOZ9Wnm3SW5tW7xUonF0rYKtobZ94jyGdpaAeehVbbab2iV3idfgM).

[Related challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/127291/75323)

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins. If you liked the challenge, consider upvoting it... And happy golfing!

Comment: What if the code has a tab character? In TIO this makes the code formatting start with `<pre><code>` and HTML formatting to insert the tab, along with a bunch of other edge cases.

Comment: @ValueInk TIO also uses random ids for its link, but this challenge has nothing more to do with the actual TIO than inspiration.

Comment: @ValueInk sorry, I didn't understand your concern.

Comment: If you have a literal tab character `\t`, the code needs to be formatted differently to display it correctly, or something, so on TIO it will emit something like `<pre><code>&#9;print 3</code></pre>` instead of `(four spaces)(tab)print 3` (because otherwise SE will change the tab into 4 spaces or something). Do we need to handle this case???

Comment: @ValueInk I tweaked the specs to guarantee that whitespace won't be too annoying

Comment: So if somebody attempts to put in some invalid code as input, what should our response be? Is that a valid test case?

Comment: @ouflak in those cases, the expected behaviour undefined. I think the linked Python code I wrote would behave correctly, but I did nothing to take care of it. You don't need to worry. If it still works, great! If it raises an error, fine by me. If it ruins the format of your string, still ok.

Comment: Can we take a multi-line string as a list (just like what the [Keg answer]()https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199503/92069 did?)

Comment: Seems like almost every answer is taking byte count as a parameter... Is that not wrong? (Oh nvm i see it can be done wither way)

Comment: @a'_' yes you can, as per the input section specs

Answer (score 7):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>98</s> <s>95</s> 94 bytes

Really simple string interpolation. I don't think there's all that much to optimize here that will save a lot of bytes.

Takes the byte count as a parameter in order to save 3 bytes, as per Kevin Cruijssen's suggestion.

```ruby
->n,b,c,l{"# #{n}, #{b} bytes

#{c.gsub /^/,' '*4}

You can [try it online][tio]!

[tio]: "+l}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tU9BboMwELzvK7YhUqTUtS@5FIX2DemljUgqYeMAEtgIr2sRxNsJRL3kAbnMjmZmR7udl/10SU7T24dhkilWD6sIo8GMbEY5ouxJO4BoULxwXqL4FWyDm@1uBDhajyozmFLXY0VoTV0ZfU6psucXgPuMcfVaj5PJGo0JFpocV6VtWpjNR0HZfIms97zTWQ6tJ4eXdFlkuHjcVdd/ynCpnr7m46Ekal0sRAiB99aTl5or24iQkSo//5L8EHbh/bv4UQd47pM3)

Comment: Looks fairly simple to me, you are right. But simple doesn't mean it doesn't deserve a +1!

Comment: -3 bytes by taking the byte-count as additional input `b` and replacing the `#{c.size}` with `#{b}`. The challenge states it's optional to take the length as input.

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>56</s> <s>53</s> <s>52</s> <s>51</s> 50 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
“# ÿ, ÿ¡Ï“I4ú»"[tio]"D“You€© [try€•€Ø]ÿ!“s¶·ý„: IJ
```

Inputs in the order `name`, `byte-count`, `[code-lines]`, `link`, where the `[code-lines]` is a list of lines.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UcMcZYXD@3WA@NDCw/1ArqfJ4V2HditFl2Tmxyq5AAUi80sfNa05tFIhuqSoEsh61LAISB6eEXt4vyJQuvjQtkPbD@991DDPSsHT6///gKL89KLEXAW/xNxUBY/UolQuQwMDrmil5PyUVCUdpfT81GIglQGUUIrlyigpKSi20tcHWqZXVJqnrwwA)

**50 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) alternative (credit to *@Grimmy*):**

```
“:# ÿ, ÿ¡Ï“I4ú»“You€© [try€•€Ø][tio]!“Â6£R¨¶·ýÀ$ú«
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UcMcK2WFw/t1gPjQwsP9QL6nyeFdh3YDGZH5pY@a1hxaqRBdUlQJZD1qWAQkD8@IjS7JzI9VBKo43GR2aHHQoRWHth3afnjv4QYVoM7V//8HFOWnFyXmKvgl5qYqeKQWpXIZGhhwRSsl56ekKukopeenFgOpDKCEUixXRklJQbGVvj7QTL2i0jx9ZQA)

**Explanation:**

```python
“# ÿ, ÿ¡Ï“  # Push dictionary string "# ÿ, ÿ bytes", where the `ÿ` are automatically
            # filled with the first two implicit inputs (name & byte-count)
I           # Push the third input-list of code-lines
 4ú         # Prepend 4 spaces before each line of code
   »        # And join it by newlines
"[tio]"     # Push string "[tio]"
       D    # Duplicate it
        “You€© [try€•€Ø]ÿ!“
            # Push dictionary string "You can [try it online]ÿ!", where the `ÿ` is
            # automatically filled with the "[tio]"
s           # Swap to get "[tio]" at the top of the stack again
¶           # Push a newline character
 ·          # Double it, which in the legacy version built in Python works with strings
  ý         # And join the stack by this double newline as delimiter
„:          # Push string ": "
   I        # Push the fourth input (link)
    J       # Join the entire stack together without delimiter
            # (after which the result is output implicitly)

“:# ÿ, ÿ¡Ï“ # Push dictionary string ":# ÿ, ÿ bytes", where the `ÿ` are automatically
            # filled with the first two implicit inputs (name & byte-count)
I4ú»        # Same as above
“You€© [try€•€Ø][tio]!“
            # Push dictionary string "You can [try it online][tio]!"
 Â          # Bifurcate it; short for Dulpicate & Reverse Copy
  6£        # Only leave the first 6 characters (the "![oit]")
    R       # Reverse it to "[tio]!"
     ¨      # Remove the last character: "[tio]"
¶·ý         # Same as above
À           # Rotate once towards the left, so the leading ":" becomes trailing
 $          # Push the fourth input (link) and a 1
  ú         # Prepend this link-string with that 1 space
   «        # And append it to the earlier created string
            # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to use the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `“# ÿ, ÿ¡Ï“` is `"# ÿ, ÿ bytes"` and `“You€© [try€•€Ø]ÿ!“` is `"You can [try it online]ÿ!"`.

Comment: Cool answer +1! String compression ftw

Comment: Good golfs, I'm not finding anything shorter. Here's an [alternative 50](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UcMcK2WFw/t1gPjQwsP9QL6nyeFdh3YDGZH5pY@a1hxaqRBdUlQJZD1qWAQkD8@IjS7JzI9VBKo43GR2aHHQoW2Hth/ee2jF4QYVoM7V//8HFOWnFyXmKvgl5qYqeKQWpXIZGhhwRSsl56ekKukopeenFgOpDKCEUixXRklJQbGVvj7QTL2i0jx9ZQA)

Comment: @Grimmy Oh, original alternative! Shall I add it to my answer, or you want to post it as separated answer, since the approach is quite different than mine?

Comment: I'm not gonna make a separate answer, feel free to add it if you want to!

Answer (score 5):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <s>102</s> 94 bytes

-6 bytes thanks to Kevin Cruijssen!

```
func[l n c u][reduce["#"rejoin[l","]n{bytes

   }c{

You can [try it online][tio]!

[tio]:}u]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY29TgMxEIR7P8WwERU/p@Q6PwWiQ9YWjm@PGJn1ybFRTlGe/TgS0VEwzTTzzVdkWF5lcGxGu4xNg0tQBDR2RYYWxNGGinzkqC7RI7Ge93OVozEALuFszFtuCF7hapkRK7KmqMKuxsx3xlzbXhrzMpWoFSNoFRJ2O9BocXOy819S/LsgMQj3dKh1OtquW@nn0rTb/DDm9kBP/84vskpf5nrIip6w7UHJf@4Hj5PF6WH7p3C67ntavgE)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Oh, yes! Apparently I didn't read the question carefully enough :)

Comment: Your code looks "funny" because it looks like you have some strings in there with the `"` but then I can't understand what is wrapping the template string.

Comment: @RGS I don't have just one template string. The argument of the `reduce` function is a block, containing strings (they remain unchanged) and `words` (let's say they are variables) which are `reduced` (evaluated). The multline string is enclosed in `{}`

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I noticed, thanks. I tried editing the question to make it more clear. Thanks for the explanation Galen!

Answer (score 4):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>134</s> <s>132</s> <s>125</s> 119 bytes

```php
# <?=($a=$argv)[1].", $a[2] bytes

".preg_replace("/^/m","    ",$a[3])."

You can [try it online][tio]!

[tio]: $a[4]";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xY4xDoIwAEX3nqJWBklIG9BFlJAwObI4mKaaghWIQJvS0nD6il7Cv7zl5eWrVnm/hec82wU8C7hu5pDGDKMIBpwmDFaLERMACCstmocWque12CFyJwOKEFyHotXcsxAjAG7SwpqPkBq9wM5AOfbdKBg1nWQbAH5Mv@UDQyfvfXkpfRwf//agNUZNKSHOObxIa2wlcC0H4rip23zOnqNN5uL1Luz1Aw)

Finally an easy job for PHP!

EDIT: easily saved 2 bytes with concatenation in first `<?=`

EDIT 2: saved another 7 bytes, just remembered that multi-lines strings work in PHP with `"`

EDIT 3: and another 6 with using `/^/m` instead of `/\n/`

Comment: Good job here! +1 for you!

Comment: You can also take advantage of NL's in strings instead of `\n` too. Obviously, I changed it a bit to be able to use it, but just an idea (118 bytes): https://tio.run/##xU7NjsIgGLzzFCz2YJMKYdcY60@87tGraTggfrZoBSyfqz49y64P4Vwmk/nJhC6kNKKrzXpc6HWhh/anbKTirKKFbj4V3T8RIiGMn7x1Y0ZoBqvgEXp/gKxZlXNfqiw5I2Tnb9RoRxscntQi9a63DlSD1qsPQv558Tc8VWyZUtp@b5OU83cd6BBDXAhh8lLr@yOPqM0ZHqbTrgVu/EVcbxBzyUUh63paS6FdvMMwQbiEXqN17cuYjV70Cw

Comment: @640KB Thanks! improved it with `str_replace` ;)

Comment: @640KB actually rolled back to the 119 version, the problem with your version and the improve I made on it is that there is not the 4 spaces in front of the first line of displayed code :/ so it would be a 120 with those spaces added..

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>125</s> <s>121</s> <s>119</s> 113 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to kronicmage
-2 bytes thanks to xnor

```hs
(l!b)c t="# "++l++", "++show b++" bytes\n"++(("\n    "++)=<<c)++"\n\nYou can [try it online][tio]!\n\n[tio]: "++t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7BDoIwEER/Zbp6aFMViTcCd@@eDHAAQkJjXQgsMX49tuqe3uzOTHZolkfv/bZpr1rTQQragaz11tIhwjKML7RBoX1Lv1QcdlpTxQgT2BR53plwr7ji@7iiaxilzG84wcjecV@X4sZaRcOXspiT7dk4RoFplZvM2EPT9fcMQeFyNihJq9QES0oH0qxcZIaF5mOq3DE1VIMGkWnJkiQ0n@aVk93wb9k@)

Comment: You can shave 4 bytes by using (=<<) instead of concatMap in your first answer (which you've already done in your second answer)

Comment: I liked how you defined your `!` function! Good job +1

Comment: You can cut a paren pair with `(("\n    "++)=<<lines c)`

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 102 bytes

```
(n,b,c,l)=>`# ${n}, ${b} bytes

${c.replace(/^/gm, '    ')}

You can [try it online][tio]!

[tio]: `+l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYzLCoMwFET3@YpbFaqYGsRNEew3dFvEYkzjo8Qb0SiK@O3WOoszcGDmyyc@iL7pzG267yUmu4u0oIIqL3nkNjgrbvRgsUGxGDkQ4qwi6GWnuJAue7OqpXCFI1dvI@SlRxAcITX9Ao0BjapBmaWm0dmFkLNjyH21C42DVjJQunJLdK3nYmqNEFkUrPCk4m3x4TDHMPvhX9TGdEPM2HES9CMyuzs3keV5@w8)

"/^/gm" is a Global Multi-line replace of start line (^)

Comment: You can save a byte by removing the space at `gm,'`. :)

Comment: Welcome to this community! Really good job here :D +1

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>97</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>118</s></sup> 116 bytes

Added 28 bytes to fix a bug kindly pointed out by [RGS](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/75323/rgs).

Saved 2 bytes thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)!!!

```python
lambda n,b,c,l,x='\n':f"""# {n}, {b} bytes

    {c.replace(x,x+' '*4)}

You can [try it online][tio]!

[tio]: {l}"""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZHBa4MwFMbv@SueEWZs0znXnmSFwi7bYbDDLsPKiDbO0PQpGotF/Nu72LXdaTBYLu/L4@X7fkmqgylKnB/z5fqoxS7dCECe8oxr3i29NXpRTil1oceBQ58OkB6MbAgBu/rstpaVFplkHe@mHniThT8Q8l62kAmE2NQHUAZK1AplEhtVJg4hpxpBrwfrbEPxE5ZAX08gMKckKzdy7Jxxugi6aUhJW@uxWxhTNVEQWJPbusXArb5vQElVKzQsZ6MjBy2RjU4@h7FwsOd9n5yn6IxOFnd2e4l/Es1Wan1NXxMLx5zQtzokDB01KoQpMJyFjpqFvh34Faq42P0L6kWYQu6EUZn4eZY81h@JFW9qJ5vVij3n8WPZook1d5OHe@7yMLkJVtq/0plCNaAa9AzIvUQQsBdabcD@ytb5G@LxCw)

Takes code length as a parameter to save 3 bytes.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your submission ! If you check Haskell's test case, the second line of code isn't indented!

Comment: You can [save one extra byte](https://tio.run/##pZHNaoQwFIX3PsU1Qhs7sdZOV9IBoZt2Ueiim6JSohNrmMxVNA4ziM8@Teavq0Kh2eTkcvKdQ9LudN3gfF8tsr3i62LJAVnBSqbiingw4sRgLCYodlr0GWYIZo3lZOVHM0DJEVLd7UBqaFBJFHmqZZO71nBQMYxqIgaOX7AA8nYIhDlxymYp7OQUu41hO4uIM3TKTmut2z4OQ4O47QYMvfbYlDhtJ1HTiloiAyWQWpLPwG4MzH3fd04uEpCbhztzPMc/834llLqkZw4hhLqRb3TkUHSlVQgzoBhErgwi3xh@LVWfcf8q9cp1LdZcy5L/PEuVqs/ciHe5Fn2S0JcqfWoG1KliXv54zzwW5VdhovxLO13LHmSP1xrERiBw2HAll2B@ZeX@reL@Gw) by deleting the space between a newline and `You`. Also, I mean that in my Haskell test case, the output has two lines of indented code but yours doesnt

Comment: @RGS Ok, got it now - problem fixed! :-)

Comment: I can't really be sure now, but taking multiline code as a list of lines and joining with "\n&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" _might_ be shorter!

Comment: Be shorter just to use '\n' instead of x.

Comment: @S.S.Anne You can't use escapes (\\) in f-string expressions (inside (`{` and `}`)..

Comment: [116 bytes](https://tio.run/##pZHBa4MwFMbv@SueEWZs0znXnmSFwi7bYbDDLsPKiDbO0PQpGotF/Nu72LXdaTBYLu/L4@X7fkmqgylKnB/z5fqoxS7dCECe8oxr3i29NXpRTil1oceBQ58OkB6MbAgBu/rstpaVFplkHe@mHniThT8Q8l62kAmE2NQHUAZK1AplEhtVJg4hpxpBrwfrbEPxE5ZAX08gMKckKzdy7Jxxugi6aUhJW@uxWxhTNVEQWJPbusXArb5vQElVKzQsZ6MjBy2RjU4@h7FwsOd9n5yn6IxOFnd2e4l/Es1Wan1NXxMLx5zQtzokDB01KoQpMJyFjpqFvh34Faq42P0L6kWYQu6EUZn4eZY81h@JFW9qJ5vVij3n8WPZook1d5OHe@7yMLkJVtq/0plCNaAa9AzIvUQQsBdabcD@ytb5G@LxCw) with a multiline string.

Comment: @ovs Nice one - thanks! :-)

Answer (score 3):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), <s>83 109 101</s> 95 bytes

```
{n,b,c,l->"""# $n, $b bytes

${c.prependIndent()}

You can [try it online][tio]!

[tio]: $l"""}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZBRT8IwFIWf7a@4FB62pLAlGIMkEI2IDiEaBzGG8DC6CgvldhkdMAm/fXYbJtqX23Pbc@7XbpSWEeb7QIJOMk@/opGiC5avkwhXDDzUDH5FVW1o9i9b6OUnZEvGmWz2KaV1aCCDxhKWmRY7Qhon3ooTEQsMPQwFass@E/KpUuABwtyMhEiDKocu5jpSixohZe1CQ5rAc/6VImyDCC0bTuSqAMVgK6AH9KVkp1WTq7BsUvrPAGbFhlRb9FlIqeCgEhnWqE3O5mpllQJXem3MRUarUpeTCDdF6FrreNd1HAPWSlJ06vWsc73POE7unI6TTN/fvCk/TtzbwezmKfAPj96DUlnHVa4cHH3eHmdDPv6O2iN/OJq56UfiOAd@Twm5qtj@fL1VvI5dmFiJxEoO2yDnPw)

-6 bytes thanks to @snail_

-2 bytes thanks to @ovs

-6 bytes since `prependIndent` has a default of 4 spaces

Comment: Unfortunately your submission doesn't indent the code correctly when it is multiline! I hope you can fix it :)

Comment: @RGS lol damn, that adds quite a few bytes, but fixed

Comment: still, good job! +1

Comment: you can use `String.prependIndent` to save some bytes. https://tio.run/##NU/BboMwDD2Pr/AyDomUVgO2lVZqj5N63mlqewgkK1GpgyCZVCG@nSXAfLGfn5/9fDO21jj@ihqsNjugX7bVeOVwRMvhH8yZweqwlLAfe@QFL3m9OpAXiJFDXEDxsKo74xnjvlw3rWoUyiNKhZYS8EHYENhv46AUCCfbPkBbMOg9qMvJO7g8h4Gp2kFck2H8cQh3oZEy6KOnYBTFXcEeyKcxZO6URk4dQl6TNHuL3j82@dajma0VXm3l@TC2ntHCaLwFneikcpVLqzzJNkm@TTPRuUp6feO/tdTboeEqX3bxaRWf9IxFw/gH

Comment: a multiline string is 2 bytes shorter: https://tio.run/##NU/LboMwEDzXX7FxOdiSExVoGxIpOVbKuacqysFgN1ghawR2pAjx7dQ86st6dnZmZ2/WVQaHh6zAGbsH9u0ag1cBJ3QC/sFcOayPyxcOQ4ciF4Wo1kdK6StEKCDKIX863RISdcWmbnStUZ1QaXSMQniU94T8WA@FRDi75gnGgcWQQF/OYf9lRchU9xBVwbYffj3CXRpkHDryMsZEeddwAPplLZ07hVVTh9K3OEnfycfnNtsFNLOVxqsrAz@ObWa0MAZvo062SvvSJ2UWp9s42yWpbH2pgr4OtzoWArFxq1i8xGQlJj3npB/@AA (combined with snail_'s suggestion)

Comment: Thanks both of you!

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 60 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
i`# {V}, {W} ßs

{XmiSp4 R}

YŒ ¯n [try Š Ò‚][o]!

[o]:
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=aWAjIHtWfSwge1d9IN8acwoKe1htaVNwNCBSfQoKWYwgr24gW3RyeSCKII3Sgl1bk29dIQoKW5NvXTog&input=Imh0dHBzOi8vdGlvLnJ1bi8jcHl0aG9uMyIKIlB5dGhvbiAzIgoyMwoibGFtYmRhIHg6IHgrMQpwYXNzCnBhc3Mi)

Comment: +1 nice handling of newline code blocks!

Answer (score 2):

### [W](https://github.com/A-ee/w) `j`, 77 bytes

```
# "a", "ck" bytes
"c'
,"
    ":@\+"

You can [try it online][tio]!

[tio]: "b
```

### Explanation

````
% Header section
# "               % The beginning header
   a              % The first input (the language name)
    ", "          % The comma & space
        ck        % The length of the program (taken at the 3rd input)
          " bytes % Appended with " bytes"
"                 % And a trailing newline

% Code section
c           % The third input
'
,           % Splitted by a newline
"
    "      % Add string representing a newline and 4 spaces
      :    % Stack: '\n'split(c), "    ", "    "
       @   % Stack: "     ",'\n'split(c), "    "
        \  % Join with 4 spaces
         + % Prepend 4 spaces

% Link section
          "

You can [try it online][tio]!

[tio]: "   % The template
         b % The second input
```
````

Comment: Nice answer +1!

Comment: This also calculates the byte-count, but it's just 1 byte longer than without calculation.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 10, 141 bytes

```java
(n,b,c,l)->{var t="";for(var p:c)t+="    "+p+"\n";return t.format("# %s, %d bytes\n\n%s\nYou can [try it online][tio]!\n\n[tio]: "+l,n,b,t);}
```

Takes the byte-count as integer-input, and the code as an array of String-lines.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##PVBBbsIwELz3FVMjpESYQK9E9NxLUaWeKuDgOAZMk3Vkb6gQytupXaVcdmc1s@vxnNVFzc/19103KgS8K0u3J8ASG39Q2mCTRuCTvaUjdDYCkkmDSo7Mdg/9j9HkZVwanmIJrNhqbEBY3zOSldSyyeevt4vy4LUQ5cH5LA3dSuc8W4v0mph1M7EjUXrDvSdwEVWt4kxMMA0S0xrVlU3Y0Y6msX65HloRtuyvsAxHjSWz37J1@@ck@kOreLeRyQPn5XAvk7@ur5rob7R5cbZGGzPIHr9S@RjANbBpC9dz0UWKG8qo0Jn48O7oVYuNag3ejDdC4mW5lCDz88jmJrSrIyOOzoTYTkk3SIgTcxdWi0W0V/ieFhORj9kN918)

**Explanation:**

```java
(n,b,c,l)->{    // Method with four parameters and String return-type
  var t="";     //  Temp-String, starting empty
  for(var p:c)  //  Loop over the code-lines:
    t+="    "   //   Append four spaces,
       +p       //   the code-line itself,
       +"\n";   //   and a newline to this temp-String
  return t.format("# %s, %d bytes\n\n%s\nYou can [try it online][tio]!\n\n[tio]: "
                //  Return this String above, where:
    +l,         //   The link is appended at the end
    n,          //   The first `%s` is replaced with the name `n`
    b,          //   The `%d` is replaced with the byte-count `b`
    t);}        //   And the second `%s` is replaced with the temp-String
```

Comment: Standard string formatting method, right? +1 for your work!

Answer (score 2):

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), 117 bytes

Just a normal string interpolation here.

```
Fn.new{|a,b,c,d|"# %(a), %(b) bytes

%("    "+c.split("
").join("
    "))

You can [try it online][tio]!

[tio]: "+d}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JVDbbqpAAHzfr9iuaQI5BAyXok2atNWCUHtBUcCmD1xWWcCFwipie77dQ3rmYWaSSSaTaWtML8ewhoQyXFfwDl4MKlLcfv@EQiTEQvKDBvCaC3mh54iHUcdwA8A1h2AP9CcWm6ogjEMA8WJWEtq734TnAQjKA4xDCj9Y3UHCYEkLQvHnByPl5xUAv3rblyR/L8uuYXgvtjVhmPs/RozDouCQ109EgqoIKIxikOAt2KUECShlrGpuJakvEesDlQYDe6U/ThqrNeYHqVZ292a0CDAzXfV1tR1NHrpkT/Svyg@zL/UmPb5HGy3XbMt4yMls8zIfr50Ud@5iiOOpapr43O43rtOWqVxma8@dGQtv9r4K9GDsvKysiZxmm9exVpzyx3i7t@bpUrHtduq/WfPMqQLtvCTdiUyT0ZOc@OHJc56aAxkVuh/fZ74su@c8LzpFp5ph4lgq/cnNUjaHxrMn79gaq8piaD/vjudp2z95@Qc)

Answer (score 2):

### [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 85 bytes

```
"# {U}, {V} bytes

{"    "+Wq"
" q"
    "}

You can [try it online][tio]!

[tio]: "+X
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=IiMge1V9LCB7Vn0gYnl0ZXMKCnsiICAgICIrV3EiCiIgcSIKICAgICJ9CgpZb3UgY2FuIFt0cnkgaXQgb25saW5lXVt0aW9dIQoKW3Rpb106ICIrWA==&input=IkphcHQiCjEwCiJhYmMKZGVmCmdoaSIKImh0dHBzOi8vZXRocHJvZHVjdGlvbnMuZ2l0aHViLmlvL2phcHQvP3Y9MS40LjYmY29kZT1JaU1nZTFWOUxDQjdWbjBnWW5sMFpYTUtDbnNpSUNBZ0lDSXJWM0VpQ2lJZ2NTSUtJQ0FnSUNKOUNncFpiM1VnWTJGdUlGdDBjbmtnYVhRZ2IyNXNhVzVsWFZ0MGFXOWRJUW9LVzNScGIxMDZJQ0lyV0E9PSZpbnB1dD1Ja3BoY0hRaUNqRXdDaUpoWW1NS1pHVm1DbWRvYVNJS0lpST0i)

Comment: Nice answer still! +1

Answer (score 2):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), `-pn`, <s>92</s> <s>83</s> <s>79</s> 75 bytes

```
®N®l®b`# ©N, ©b  ¬E;s\n`,÷(\    $+,)
,“0:0X“` [try it a.;][tio]!\n[tio]: ©l`+,
```

Input is: Name, link, byte count and code

### Explained

```
®N®l®b
```

We first take the inputs `name`, `link` and `byte count` and store them in variable `N`, `l` and `b` respectively.

```
`# ©N, ©b  ¬E;s\n`,
```

Next, we construct a string that represents the header. The `©N` and `©b` are used for. string interpolation, and `¬E;` is the compressed word for `byte`. Printing the string using `,` formats the string with variables.

```
÷(\ $+,)
```

Now, we item split the implicit code list and print each item with a tab appended to it.

```
<newline>,
```

Then, we print a newline to separate everything.

```
“0:0X“` [try it a.;][tio]!\n[tio]: ©l`+,
```

Finally, we construct two strings: the string `You can` (represented by `“0:0X“`) and  `[try it online][tio]!\n[tio]: ©l` (which has the variable `l` interpolated within it). The two strings are then joined and printed.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N////0Dq/Q@tyDq1LSlBWOLTSTwdIJCkoHFrjal0ck5egc3i7RgyniraOJpfOo4Y5BlYGEUAqQSG6pKhSIbNEIVHPOja6JDM/VjEmD0xbAfXnJGjr/P/vnZrOFeLpr5ttUmKWXWBexmXGFa2koaSjoFRjqK2pFKvwX7cgDwA)

### Answer History

#### 79 bytes

```
0&®N®l®b`# ©N, ©b  ¬E;s\n`,÷(`\t`$+,)
,“0:0X“` [try it a.;][tio]!\n[tio]: ©l`+,
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///fQO3QOr9D63IOrUtKUFY4tNJPB0gkKSgcWuNqXRyTl6BzeLtGQkxJgoq2jiaXzqOGOQZWBhFAKkEhuqSoUiGzRCFRzzo2uiQzP1YxJg9MWwFNyEnQ1vn/3zs1nSvE018326TELLvAvIzLjCtaSUNJR0GpxlBbUylW4b9uQR4A)

#### 83 bytes

```
0&®N®l®b`# ©N, ©b  bytes\n`,÷(`\t`$+,)
,`You can [try it online][tio]!\n[tio]: ©l`,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///fQO3QOr9D63IOrUtKUFY4tNJPB0gkKSgkVZakFsfkJegc3q6REFOSoKKto8mlkxCZX6qQnJinEF1SVKmQWaKQn5eTmZcaG12SmR@rGJMHpq2AJuQk6Pz/752azhXi6a@bbVJill1gXsZlxhWtpKGko6BUY6itqRSr8F@3IA8A)
Saved 9 bytes due to not calculating the byte count.

#### 92 bytes

```
0&®N®l÷(:⑴⑼⑹")"⑺⑻®b`# ©N, ©b  bytes\n`,(`\t`$+,)
,`You can [try it online][tio]!\n[tio]: ©l`,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///fQO3QOr9D63IOb9ewejRxy6OJex5N3KmkqfRo4q5HE3cfWpeUoKxwaKWfDpBIUlBIqixJLY7JS9DRSIgpSVDR1tHk0kmIzC9VSE7MU4guKapUyCxRyM/LycxLjY0uycyPVYzJA9NWQP05CTr//3unpnOFePrrZpuUmGUXmJdxRStpKOkoKNUYamsqxSr81y3IAwA)

Note that I haven't applied string compression yet, which would get this down to 89 bytes. I'll do it tomorrow. The code is to be given as a list where each item is an individual line.

Comment: Really impressive answer! (I didn't upvote it because I want to get the Electorate badge.)

Comment: @a'_' you've got a while left until you reach that badge though... That requires 600 upvotes, meaning it would take at least 15 days.

Comment: But there's only a 12-hour interval. That means it would take me 8 days.

Comment: @a'_' do you mean you will be upvoting a bunch of questions for the next days?

Comment: In fact I've already done it.

Answer (score 2):

## Jinja2, 102 bytes

```
# {{n}}, {{b}} bytes

{%for a in c%}
    {{a}}
{%endfor%}

You can [try it online][tio]!

[tio]: {{l}}
```

Does this count as a language? Used jinja cli from here: https://pypi.org/project/jinja2-cli/

I think it should as this is the usage to run it:

```
jinja2 tio.j2 test.json --format=json
```

It accepts a file as a program, and input in some format. That fits the definition of a language to me.

This was the input json tested with:

```
{"n": "lang_name", "b": 10, "c": ["line_1", "line_2"], "l": "https://example.com"}
```

Comment: Funny submission ;) +1

Answer (score 2):

## C (gcc), 162 bytes

```
t(n,b,c,l)char*n,*c,*l;{for(printf("# %s, %d bytes\n\n    ",n,b);*c;)putchar(*c++)-10?:printf("    ");printf("\n\nYou can [try it online][tio]!\n\n[tio]: %s",l);}
```

There may be spaces after a trailing newline but I'm not sure if I'll be able to find a solution (or if a solution is even needed).

You can [try it online](https://tio.run/##jY@xjsIwDIb3PoXxCSkJRjoYbmgGBp4CEYZi4IjUc1AJSAjx7D23FQw3nMjkSP/32x9Pv5nbNhuhLTHVlo9V44Qck6v9/ZAac2qi5IPBDxifCcY72N7y/hwkCOhDUtJ6x96eLrmjjePJxE5nn4vyifZB65/fjl2lC3AlsM7NDWKGJHWU/WadY9qMukA/lboT9Sr/aBWFnyqKuaa4s8W96EqzwSUYVbBIMPuaE@AbKuGvi@4bbMI7OgGH6Eso4NDwv1MfeVmFQUvPRi0qHu0v)!

Comment: Looking promising! Will wait for the rest.

Comment: @RGS There's no way to do it without a loop so expect +25 bytes or more.

Comment: @RGS Take a look.

Comment: looks good to me! +1 and thanks for fixing your submission !

Answer (score 1):

## Charcoal, <s>67</s> 56 bytes

```
Ｆ⪪“`⊟«Ｍ["Þ…εＵ↑⁵ï²¹@↧≡⊗»⭆∧⌕´r⪪ιυＮτ⁰⬤N➙⁺⁰UＹ⟧MyoJb⎇»﹪”¶«ι Ｓ
```

You can [try it online](https://tio.run/#charcoal)!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY/PSgJRFIfX9RSn62YGrFllYCJBq4IikBYxV0gHy4Hhjty5BhKBQllJCC0iglKCUNCsqAwmZ3Xd6zucF5hHmGYiafd9h/Pnd4xijht2zgqCA5uDkilZplBIjLI4ZZCviIJDOeUAQFkEe3YZjBwDXfAKmAJsZpmskNWFaWcXooZfSpI4EMqIqsLx/NwON5lQTHV1hgTIv2ywUllkRMiHihqWT4JAJ@t/qaI9KSedWElpThqWE5H7Xgd7Paze72OjLfu@N9ApGbew2pkMfW@I9WusDcev8l26a1jv4uUjNm7lCAd1vOji1Y385OH8xJ2e@d7L9BRrb/j8tI2tO6x9h7Lrey62u1sVezOPzXM58t3w2IP8kv2JC773EWUoClFykpoWPrvEy0yLGbPA2WDxyPoB) Link is to verbose version of code. Assumes you're not worried about Charcoal's default output padding, which can be turned off at a cost of 2 bytes. Explanation: Each input has a certain amount of text that appears before it, which always ends in a space, so the loop prints the text and space before each input. Because it uses separate print commands for the inputs, the newlines in the code block maintain the indent, but the text strings themselves include carriage returns which turn off the indent (particularly applicable to the TIO gubbins). The four text strings themselves are extracted from a large compressed string.